# Check if website is down

Tags: hosting, website

My webhost seems to go down more often lately. This is really annoying and right now I don't know how often this happens. To be able to check if my website is offline I need something (maybe an application or service online) that maybe each hour can contact the site and see if the site is offline or online. Maybe send me an email if the site is down.

Can you give me some tips on where to find this application / service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use http://www.pingdom.com/ to monitor our company web-site. There is a free plan which allows you to monitor one 'item' (I say item because it is capable of monitoring many things) which can then send you an e-mail/text/etc alert if it was to go down.

Answer (score 1):

http://mon.itor.us/

http://site24x7.com/index.html

or install zabbix/nagios

Answer (score 0):

To add another to the realm, we are using AlertFox. They have a nice free plan that even includes [free web transaction monitoring](http://www.alertfox.com/) within Firefox! So you run your test in a real web browser and get a page screenshot if something fails. The screenshots are very useful to make your hosting company (our in our case the payment gateway provider) believe that there was *really* an error. The power of screenshots is amazing ;)